# Choosing 2005 balls from 10000 red, 10000 yellow, and 10000 green balls

Tags: combinatorics

Below is the problem I want to solve:

> There are 10000 identical red balls, 10000 identical yellow balls and 10000 identical green balls. In how many different ways can we select 2005 balls so that the number of red balls is even and the number of yellow balls is odd?

I am trying to solve using generating functions, with the following reasoning:

Let $R, Y, G$ be a generating function representing number of red, yellow and green balls respectively. Since no. of red balls is even, no. of yellow balls is odd, and no. of green balls doesn't matter (subject to restriction of total no. of balls = 2005), we have:

$$
R: 1 + x^2+x^4+x^6+\dots \\
Y: x + x^3+x^5 + \dots \\
G: 1 + x + x^2+x^3 + \dots
$$

Since 2005 < 10000, the fact that no. of balls is restricted to 10000 doesn't matter, and above functions could be treated as infinite series for convenience. Hence, coefficient of $x^{2005}$ in the product of $RYG$ is the solution to the given question

$$
\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{x}{1-x^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x}\\
= \frac{x}{(1-x)^3\cdot(1+x)^2}
$$

Now, I am stuck at this step. How do I expand this to the "open" form to get the coefficient of $x^{2005}$? Also, is there a flaw in the above reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

I'd write it as $$x(1-x^2)^{-2}(1-x)^{-1}$$ Then I'd use the binomial theorem to write $$(1-x^2)^{-2}=1+2x^2+3x^4+4x^6+\cdots$$ so we're looking for the coefficient of $x^{2004}$ in $$(1+2x^2+3x^4+4x^6+\cdots)(1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots)$$ So now you just have to identlfy where the terms in $x^{2004}$ come from when you multiply the two series, and you will have to evaluate a sum to get the final answer. OK?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to use generating functions, but if you really must, Gerry's answer is straightforward:  it is easy to see that for each term in $1 + 2x^2 + 3x^4 + \cdots$ up to $1002x^{2004}$, there is exactly one term in $1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots$ that, when multiplied, gives a term of the form $x^{2004}$.  Hence what you want is the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{1002} (k+1)$.

For a non-GF approach, since the number of balls to be selected is less than the number of balls of any given type, we can use direct enumeration.  If $2r$ is the number of red balls chosen, then the number of ways to choose an odd number of yellow balls is $(2005 - 2r + 1)/2 = 1003 - r$, and the number of green balls is uniquely determined in order to make exactly $2005$ total balls selected.  So the total number of ways is $$\sum_{r=0}^{1002} 1003 - r = \sum_{r=1}^{1003} r = \frac{1003(1004)}{2} = 503506.$$

Comment: I don't *have* to use generating functions per se. I am self-learning generating functions and recurrences, so trying to solve as many such problems as possible using generating functions. Good answer by the way, thanks.